# The meaning of "meaning"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'd like to know the meaning of "meaning" in the following sentences:

> Please note that we have implemented a 1 post approval process for new
>   users. **Meaning**, a newly registered user with no posts
>   under their belt can post, but will have to wait until a moderator
>   approves it before it shows up.

Comment: It would have been better stylistically, and perhaps also easier to understand, if the period had been replaced with a comma, and a conjunction introduced: “We have implemented a 1-post approval process for new users, meaning that a newly registered user…”.

Comment: You also see "Meaning:" with a colon, which is perhaps ever clearer, if a bit modern and brassy.

Answer (score 3):

In the above sentence "Meaning" is used as a participle. You could replace it by: That is to say/i.e.

Answer (score 2):

> Please note that we have implemented a 1 post approval process for
>   new users. **Meaning**, a newly registered user with no posts under their
>   belt can post, but will have to wait until a moderator approves it
>   before it shows up.

expands to:

> Please note that we have implemented a 1 post approval process for
>   new users. **This means**, a newly registered user with no posts under their
>   belt can post, but will have to wait until a moderator approves it
>   before it shows up.